# how to output convex_hull polygon of points shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geometry, shapely, fiona

i have a shapefile of more than 8 points and i have written a code get the convex_hull geometry of of the points and output it as a shapefile using fiona. however the code returns an error saying:

**ERROR**:TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, point, shape
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
outshape = fiona.open(".cache\ca2_points\ca2_points.shp")
with fiona.open('.cache/mew.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', outshape.schema.copy(), outshape.crs)   as output:
    for feat in output:
        feat = MultiPoint([shape(point['geometry']) for point in fiona.open(outshape)])
        output.write(feat)
```

Comment: please **edit** your existing question if there is a problem with it

Comment: am experiencing an error "OSError: collection not open for reading", at for feat in output. any ideas why

Comment: The result of  `feat = MultiPoint([shape(point['geometry']) for point in fiona.open(outshape)])`is one Polygon, so the schema (`outshape.schema.copy()' = Point)  is not correct and you don't need a for loop

Comment: Look at New in the answer of the original question